# Single word request that means 'make a question stronger"

Tags: single-word-requests

If I, for example, ask a question, and then later on someone answers the question with an answer that only makes the question - for lack of a better term - more stronger...what do you call that term?

**Example:** I ask...*"how did we measure and determine that space is infinite if "infinity" by definition means immeasurable?"* to which someone answers *"it's because we've determined that infinity exists and space fits that definition"*. To that answer, I'd like to reply *"if anything, your answer only _________ens my question."*

Basically "_________ens" would mean that if my question was asked with only %80 perplexity (%20 understanding) and I asked the question in order to get better understanding (with the ultimate outcome being %0 perplexity/%100 understanding), now after your answer, my question stands at %100 perplexity (%0 understanding), essentially making my question bolder.
So if the question was written...."blah blah blah blah?" , it would now be written "**blah blah blah blah???**"

Comment: Doesn't "strengthens" work here? If not, what do you think it lacks?

Comment: Not sure there's a good single word with your meaning, but it's an interesting question; you could say something like "that makes my question more important/urgent" or "that answer only increases my confusion".

Comment: "Validates"? "Reinforces"? "Epitomizes?" None of them quite work without tinkering with your sentence...

Comment: Essentially, I think that the 'answer' in your example is unsatisfactory, and seen to be so by at least the questioner. Hence 'Your unsatisfactory/inadequate answer merely endorses the question's importance.'

Comment: @Royster Interesting choice of words. Had it been a claim I was making, those words would be %100 fitting. But since I'm not making a statement/claim but rather asking a question...they don't seem quite fitting.

Comment: Why does it have to include -ens?

Comment: [*now you've gone all defensive, which just **underlines** my question*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22just+underlines+my+question%22) I didn't find ***sharpens*** in such contexts, but that one also works for me. On the other hand, if I was actually writing the text I wouldn't want to be constrained by "single-word request" thinking - I'd more likely use something like *...which just **makes** my question **all the more relevant***.

Comment: Starting with the question . . . Did we even measure infinity?

Answer (score 1):

I would use **substantiate**.

> #### Substantiate
>
> to show something to be true, or to support a claim with facts:
>
> - *We have evidence to substantiate the allegations against him.*
> - *Reports that children had been hurt have not been substantiated.*

[[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/substantiate)]

Or **reinforce**

> #### Reinforce
>
> If something reinforces an idea or opinion, it provides more proof or support for it and makes it seem true:
>
> - *The final technical report into the accident reinforces the findings of initial investigations.*

[[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/reinforce)]

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

Emphasizes, highlights

Comment: You should include dictionary definitions and your reasons why these are suitable (see the existing answer)